# Bash variable search and replace instead of sed

Tags: regex, bash, parsing, variables, replace

[See Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158149/bash-menu-driven-text-file-viewer-presenter-tool)

[See Github Project](https://github.com/mattinclude/Bash/tree/master/sopman)

I need to parse out instances of `+word+` line by line (replace `+word+` with blank). I'm currently using the following (working) sed regex:

```
newLine=$(echo "$line" | sed "s/+[a-Z]\++//g")
```

This violates "SC2001" according to "ShellCheck" validation;

```
SC2001: See if you can use ${variable//search/replace} instead.
```

I've attempted several variations without success (The string "+word+" remains in the output):

```
newLine=$(line//+[a-Z]+/)
newLine=$(line/+[a-Z]+//)
newLine=$(line/+[a-Z]\++/)
newLine=${line//+[a-Z]+/}
and more..
```

I've heard that in some cases sed is necessary, but I would like to use Bash's built in find and replace if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "without success"? What was wrong with your solutions?

Comment: The string "+word+" remains in the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The substitution in parameter expansion doesn't use regular expressions, but [patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html). To get closer to regular expressions, you can turn on extended patterns:

```
shopt -s extglob
new_line=${line//++([a-Z])+}
```

Comment: Please provide example that exactly reproduces the behavior of : `sed "s/+[a-Z]\++//g"`. The provided example does not seem to be parsing `+word+`.

Comment: @MatthewA.Brassey: The behaviour of `[a-Z]` depends on the current locale. Use a more explicit character class (e.g. `[[:alnum:]]`).

Comment: [[:alnum:]] was the solution! Thank you.